# How can I obtain an access token using infor api and OAuth2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build an SPFX webpart using Infor ION API workflow, the webpart is build using React and typescript.
I got the credentials file containing the information like ci, cs, saak, sask, etc... from the developer working on the endpoints.
but now I'm stuck on where to go next, because it's not the usual authentication process.

I tried using libraries for the front-end but I would get CORS error, and I can't edit the API endpoints themselves because I don't have access to them.
I also tried to create a middle man azure function to obtain the access token and pass it through an endpoint but that was an entire thing by itself.
I would appreciate the help and guidance on what to do next as I am fairly new to this